# laravel guzzle not work page stuck on reloading

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

```
public function getGuzzleRequest()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/poster');
    $response = $request->getBody();
    print_r($response);
}
```

laravel guzzle not work page stuck on reloading

Comment: Do you have a server running at `http://localhost:8000`? Is `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/poster` reachable in your browser?

Comment: I would also recommend dispatching internal routes instead of using Guzzle for same-origin requests

Comment: yes running localhost 8000. and api reachable in even postman i

Comment: when i use guzzle call for in the same laravel project for api response then browser still reload

Comment: even i change server 8000 to 8080 but still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build in PHP development server (artisan: serve) is single threaded so will hang,
 for example http://localhost:8000 will not work. 
 Try using a real server (Apache /nginx). 
Something like 'http://ip.jsontest.com'

```
public function getGuzzleRequest(){
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->get('http://youripadress:8000/api/v1/poster');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
print_r($response);
```

}

You can as well provide an alternative with php curl function.

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$targeturl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
            curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

but make sure u use your are using a real server, if possible supplement the localhost with your ip address

**How to get your ip address**
 run `ifconfig` command on the command line or terminal and check on the number preceding`inet`.

You can learn more of guzzle on [guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) and [curl requests with php](https://codular.com/curl-with-php)

Comment: can you suggest another way instead of guzzle

Comment: you can use php curl  instead                                                                                
                 check the updates above

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `php artisan serve` start the single-threaded PHP builtin server.

As PHP docs say:

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

With the `php artisan serve` being a single thread application, you can create a virtual host or do a temporary fix like I did.

Open up two command lines. The first would be running `php artisan serve` (locally my default port is 8000). The second would run `php artisan serve --port 8001`.

Then you would update your get request to `$request = $client->get('http://youripadress:8001/api/v1/poster');`.

This should help during your testing until you are able to everything on server or a local virtual host.